# tool/suggestions for web application performance test monitoring

Tags: php, performance, apache, postgresql

I have a web application distributed over different logical and physical layers.

The application is written in php5.3 and uses postgresql version 8.3.

The web front layer has a dedicated machine and is composed of apache htppd 2 webserver running the php engine.

The db layer has another dedicated machine running postgresql. The databases data are stored on machine local file system.

The two layer (web and db) communicate over a 1gbps private network.

I need to setup a execute a performance test on my web application as a whole and the split the test on the single layers (db and web)

Do you know any tool/best practice for such a kind of test?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Regards
Alberto

Comment: You may modify your title, so that it reflects your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ab is very simple and powerful.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html

Comment: It is not appropriate to test the single layers (web and db), as requested.

Comment: It IS, however, a good way to get real-world traffic simulations.  Then you monitor your internal network and monitor your db load to see the impact.  If your DB server is pushing data to the disk at 100% capacity, you have a problem.  But a test that pushes your DB to 100% without having requests through the web server is not a real-world test.

Comment: I agree, but it is part of the question that there is a need to "split the test on the single layers".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to benchmarking with tools like [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) and [webbench](http://home.tiscali.cz/~cz210552/webbench.html), you should set up load monitoring tools that watch interface traffic, CPU and disk activity, etc.  Pick one of the many RRDTool front-ends and build some graphs, so that you can see what spikes while you run your load test.  If you see any curves with flat tops, those are your problem areas.  :-)

Check out [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), and [others from RRD World](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/rrdworld/index.en.html).

I like Cacti's user interface, and its auto-discovery is pretty handy.  But it can be tricky to keep working, and it has a lot of dependencies.  Munin is small, slick and reliable, but requires more hand-holding to configure.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is also good and produces nice [graphs](http://loadstorm.com/files/JMeter-screenshot.jpg). It can be used to test web applications and databases, amongst others.